# Test conditional validations with RSpec (and Shoulda Matchers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, shoulda

How would you test this code (with RSpec and eventually Shoulda)?

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, conditions: -> { where.not(status: "published").where.not(type: "Version") }
```

Comment: make a record. Make another record that will trip that validation. Validate the second record. Make sure the error is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can test only pre-defined validations using shoulda-matchers. If you want to test custom validations you should write your own spec implementation.